# OpenCV Missing dll files in version 2.4.10

Tags: c#, opencv, dll, emgucv

Hello I just downloaded the OpenCV version 2.4.10 from here:

http://opencv.org/releases.html

The error I am receiving my code is:

***'The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.'***

on the line

```
var image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Path.GetFullPath("testImage.png")
```

The description of the error on the official EmguCV page here:

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.

says to download 'MSVCRT 10.0 SP1 x64' (did this) and to reference the OpenCV files to the execution directory (did this).

However the OpenCV version 2.4.10 download does not contain the files:

- cudart64_42_9.dll
- cvextern.dll
- npp64_42_9.dll

which I believe are required to solve this error.

Are these files still required? If so, where can I download them?

I am running on x64 system, creating a .NET Form application and using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Not completely sure, but you may want to install from nuget. https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCV/

Comment: My project is a .NET Form application so this option is not available :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I was receiving was due to a collision between the references

**EmguCV** and **EmguCV.World**

In which both contained a definition of Image. To fix this I got rid of the EmguCV.World reference. Also if you download directly from the OpenCv site there is NOT a cvextern.dll file in the 2.4.1 version.

However the required OpenCv components to run with EmguCV is contained in the zip file that you download on the EmguCV site.